# How do I change this HTML into a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, e-commerce

I have some arbitrary text that i'd like to convert into a table with some values. I do not know if this is possible. The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="custom_meta">
    <strong>Length: </strong>
    11.22.33.44.55.66
    <br>

    <strong>Width: </strong>
    11.22.33.44.55.66
    <br>
</div>
```

And i'd like to change the output into:

```
<div class="custom_meta">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Length: </strong>
                </td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>66</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>Width: </strong>
                </td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>44</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>66</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Long story but I could not find any plugin to simply convert custom fields into tables in wp e-commerce. The first piece of code i tried flunked badly. I wanted to start by inserting the beginning bits of the HTML table by using the `.before()` function, but it ended up closing the tag before I could close it myself at the end of the closing div. I.e,

```
$(".custom_meta strong:first").before("<table><tbody><tr><td>");
```

ended up both opening and closing the tag before the first strong tag.

Comment: Do you not have access to the backend to simply output it correctly to begin with?

Comment: BTW, you should probably use `<th>` instead of those `<td><strong>`

Comment: @herby: Shouldn't you only have `<th>` tags inside of a `<thead>`?

Comment: Must admit, don't know exactly, but I'd say no. You can have headers in column, too, not only in row.

Comment: I think some basic js for parsing + jQuery templates will be simple enough.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Because it is a CMS, I wouldnt be able to manually do this every time she adds a new product

Comment: @JesseB where do i get that information from? i.e, parsing JS and jQuery templates

Comment: Here's the link to [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/), and by basic parsing I meant either implementing a regex to sort out the data, or using something like indexOf to look for the pieces.

Comment: @Rocket - No. `th` can be in a row or column; indeed, there is a `scope` property of the `th` element with which you can explicitly note whether a `th` applies to a row or column. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/th

Comment: @Chris: Ok, so it seems `<th>`s work inside any `<tr>`, not just those in `<thead>`.  Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `contents()` to find all nodes, and write a custom filter to find only the textNodes containing `.`, and use that as the source of your data values.

Something like this would work:

```
var headers = $('.custom_meta strong');
var values = $('.custom_meta').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3  // text node
        && this.nodeValue.indexOf('.') > 0;
});

var table = $('<table/>');
var tbody = $('<tbody/>');

headers.each(function(n) {
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append($('<td><strong>' + $(this).html() + '</strong></td>'));

    var itemValues = values[n].nodeValue.split('.');
    for(var i = 0; i < itemValues.length; i++) {
        tr.append($('<td>' + itemValues[i].trim() + '</td>'));
    }

    tbody.append(tr);
});

table.append(tbody);
$('.custom_meta').empty().append(table);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLJDU/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$html = $(".custom_meta").html(); //store original value
$(".custom_meta").html("<table><tbody id='mytbody'></tbody></table>"); //set html to nothing
var rows = $html.split("<br>"); //split the html based on <br>
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length - 1; i++) { //loop until i = length - 1 (- 1 because there are as many <br> tags as <strong> tags - so there would be one before and after each <br>, thus you want to get rid of the last one.
    $("#mytbody").append("<tr><th>" + $("<div></div>").html($html).find("strong:eq(" + i + ")").html() + "</th></tr>"); //create a new div temporarily, add the original html and then get the content of the strong at the current position (i)
}
```

This should at least get you started - I won't give you the entire answer, however, as you won't necessarily learn that way. All that's left is extracting the .-separated lists, and splitting those based on the ..

Regards,
Richard

Edit: see my JS fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/a6Bcu/

Comment: thanks for the comments explaining the code. Even though the questions been answered fully, i'll look through it carefully so that I can actually learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is, probably, not the cleanest solution, but it does at least work:

```
function nextSiblingToCells(that){
    var t = that.nextSibling.nodeValue.split('.');
    for (i=0;i<t.length;i++){
        $('<td />').text(t[i]).appendTo($('table tbody tr:last'));
    }
};

var table = document.createElement('table'),
    tbody = document.createElement('tbody'),
    text;

table.appendChild(tbody);

$(table).appendTo($('.custom_meta:first'));

$('strong').each(
    function(){
        text = $(this).text();
        $('<tr />').appendTo($(table)).append('<td>' + text + '</td>');
        nextSiblingToCells(this,'br');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/DAwuw/).

References:

- jQuery, from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/):

  - [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).
  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- JavaScript, from the [Mozilla Developer Network's JavaScript resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript):

  - [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nextSibling).
  - [`nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeValue).
  - [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
var table = $('<tbody></tbody>');
$('.custom_meta').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).each(function() {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>');
  var header = $(this).prevAll('strong');
  if (header.length) {
    row.append($('<td></td>').append(header));
    $.each($(this).text().split('.'), function(index, element) {
        row.append($('<td>' + element + '</td>'));
    });
    table.append(row);
  }
});
$('.custom_meta').empty().append($('<table></table>').append(table));
```

[See here for jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eBC5U/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
final_contents = "<table>"; 

$('.custom_meta').contents().each(function(){ 
     var values = []; 
    if( $(this).text().trim() === 'Length:' )
     {
         final_contents += "<tr>";
         final_contents += "<td>Length:</td>";   
     }
    else if( $(this).text().trim() === 'Width:' )
    {
         final_contents += "<tr>";
         final_contents += "<td>Width:</td>"; 
    } 

     if( this.nodeType === 3 && $(this).text().trim().length !== 0 )
         values = $(this).text().split('.'); 

     for( var i = 0; i < values.length; i++ ) 
          final_contents += "<td>"+values[i].trim() + "</td>"; 

     if( this.nodeName.trim() === 'BR' )
         final_contents += "</tr>"  
})

final_contents += "</table>";     
$('.custom_meta').html( final_contents );
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/swD8X/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's another implementation.  Honestly, most of these will work fine.

Down side for this implementation is the assumption that `<br>` will always separate the rows, and `<strong>` will always contain the header information: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/DAwuw/4/

```
var nodes = $.map($('.custom_meta:first').html().split('<br>'), function(o, i) {
    return $.trim(o);
});

var rows = $.map(nodes, function(row) {
    if (row == '') { return ''; }
    row = row.replace('</strong>', '</strong>.');
    tds = $.map(row.split('.'), function(td) { return '<td>' + td + '</td>'; }).join('\n');
    return '<tr>' + tds + '</tr>';
}).join('\n');

$('body').append($('<table></table>').append(rows));
```